# Dataset for parquet format

Tags: java, mapreduce, dataset, parquet, bigdata

I have a mapreduce program which I want to take in a parquet file. I am not able to find any parquet sample dataset on any repo or site.

Please suggest some.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just write a MR to read a dfs file and write as a parquet file.

Commands:

Use the ALTER command to set the store.format option.

```
ALTER SESSION SET `store.format` = 'parquet';
ALTER SYSTEM SET `store.format` = 'parquet';
```

[Source](https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-format/)